# Compiling ptrace in ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu

How to compile using ubuntu binary packages.

I am trying to compile the next code in ubuntu 16.06

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>

int main(int ac, char **av) {
  struct ptrace_io_desc piod;
  return 0;
}
```

but when gcc file.c -o file I get error: storage size of ‘piod’ isn’t known.I think that it is maybe exist a command to add the ptrace.h header. Also, I found a link in [Ubuntu manuals](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man2/ptrace.2.html) with a [gz file](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man2/ptrace.2.html), Can I to use this file to compile?.

Please could you help me?

Comment: The manual never mention `struct ptrace_io_desc`, why do you want to use it ?

Comment: A very quick search indicates that `ptrace_io_desc` is a FreeBSD-specific structure. Where did you read about it?

Comment: I read about here https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/26368/.

Comment: @Juan Like a programmer said, your file is for freeBSD system "FreeBSD 9.{0,1}". And you have a ubuntu OS. I will recommend you to read the manual.